# Electron - How to add react dev tool

Tags: electron

What is the easy way to add react dev tool to electron window? I try add the extension hash

`BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension('path/to/extension/ade2343nd23k234bdb').15.01`

But when the extension update, I had to manually update the string in main.js. I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a Solution for Electron <= 1.2.1 version

1- In your app folder

```
npm install --save-dev electron-react-devtools
```

2- Open your electron app, click on (view/toggle developer tools). In the **console** tab insert the following code and **hit enter**:

```
 require('electron-react-devtools').install()
```

3- Reload/refresh your electron app page and you'll see the react dev tools appear.

4- Done!

---

**See screen shots bellow**

[image: Paste/type code on console tab]

[image: hit enter]

[image: react dev tools enabled]

Comment: Note that this method only installs the react devtools for the current session; you have to do this every time you launch your application.

Comment: Package got abandoned, here's my take: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools-electron

Comment: @Zentryn you are right. Have you found a way to permanently have access to the tools without re-running this command every time we launch the app?

Comment: @DimitarNestorov attempting to install your package gets `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined`

Comment: @dWitty Electron updated the internals a while ago and I haven't had time to fix it. Some people are reporting that they can't get it to work (not using my library) even with the latest version of electron: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23662

Comment: `React DevTools can only be installed from an renderer process.` i see this when i try to execute `require('electron-react-devtools').install()`

Answer (score 9):

You can add react devtools directly from your main.js file like this

```
const installExtensions = async () => {
  const installer = require('electron-devtools-installer')
  const forceDownload = !!process.env.UPGRADE_EXTENSIONS
  const extensions = [
    'REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS',
    'REDUX_DEVTOOLS',
    'DEVTRON'
  ]

  return Promise
    .all(extensions.map(name => installer.default(installer[name], forceDownload)))
    .catch(console.log)
}

app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (dev && process.argv.indexOf('--noDevServer') === -1) {
    await installExtensions()
  }
  createWindow()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`addDevToolsExtension` is not an instance method, so you need to call `BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension('path/to/extension')`.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me (https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer#usage) -

```
npm install electron-devtools-installer --save-dev 
or 
yarn add electron-devtools-installer -D
```

```
import installExtension, { REDUX_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer';
// Or if you can not use ES6 imports
/**
const { default: installExtension, REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS } = require('electron-devtools-installer');
*/
const { app } = require('electron');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    installExtension(REDUX_DEVTOOLS)
        .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
        .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
});
```

Comment: i dont see react tab, is there something i am missing?

Comment: Did you **refresh the site** after the electron client had started up? [I had to do that in my solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77837926/16955687)

Answer (score 0):

Electron actually has [an official guide for how to install DevTools Extensions](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devtools-extension) (e.g. React Development Tools). The guide will link you to the [GitHub site of the repository which has a guide for how to proceed.](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer) The solution is similar to the answer posted by [Chetan Gawai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66240622/16955687), but I use `pnpm` and ES6 package imports.

Using `pnpm`, here is what i did:

1. `pnpm install --save-dev electron-devtools-installer`
2. Add the following code to your **main process**:

```js
import installExtension, { REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS} from 'electron-devtools-installer';
import { app } from "electron";
...
app.whenReady().then(() => {
   installExtension(REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS)
       .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
       .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
});
```

3. After the electron window has started, remember to **refresh the site in electron** (typically *ctrl+r*). You may not see the react development tools before you refresh the site (I don't know why a refresh is needed).

   - Developer Tools before refresh (the react development tools are not visible):

     [image: enter code here]
   - Developer Tools after refresh (the react development tools are visible):

     [image]

The [GitHub site for the electron-devtools-installer](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer#what-extensions-can-i-use) will have a list of different extensions that you can install.

Answer (score -1):

If you see a blank component when launching react-devtools, it's probably because you've installed the package globally as it is recommended in the react-native docs, in the debugging section. What's happening is it doesn't get connected to your app, because it's not your app-specific.

You need to install it locally.

```
npm install --save-dev react-devtools
```

or

```
yarn add -D react-devtools
```