# React Dev Tools - Unable to use profiler in Electron application

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, electron, react-devtools

The [React Profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html) plugin does not seem to be enabled in React Developer Tools when used with Electron.

I have tried the following and have had no success:

- Bundling the application in developer mode and loading it using the
  `file` protocol as opposed to `http`
- Using the `electron-devtools-installer` package
- Following the [DevTools extension](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/devtools-extension#how-to-load-a-devtools-extension) guide in the Electron documentation
- Updating React to the latest version

The only way I can get the profiler plugin to work is by loading the application via `http://localhost:8080`, but this is obviously not ideal because I cannot use the Electron API.

Here's how it looks when opening React Developer Tools in my Electron application.

[image: React Developer Tools screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927929/electron-how-to-add-react-dev-tool) SO answer to understand where I needed to make the installExtension call. Of note, I passed an array of options to the method.

```
app.on('ready', async () => {

    if (isDev) {
        await
            installExtension([REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS])
                .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
                .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
    }

    createWindow();
})
```